# Is it efficient to run my server on a live CD?

Tags: server, live-cd

For the specific server that I plan on running, I've read online that it runs faster when hosted on a Linux based OS.  I have a copy of a Ubuntu Disk.  I don't plan on hosting this server often and wondered if it was worth the trouble booting from the disk (not installing) and just running the server from the live CD?

Are there any drawbacks from being in the preview?  Will it nullify my benefits?

Comment: The only drawback will be you **Wouldn't be able to save any Work or Configuration** the second time you insert and try to use it.Why not install it in USB drive so making it portable and usable much better.

Comment: You will need to re-install and reconfigure each time you boot or make a custom iso. Regarding the performance, I can only think of Disk I/O. Interesting question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be better off creating a virtual machine for your server using one of the freely available virtualization solutions like VirtualBox.

This permits you to host the server occasionally as desired, but does not suffer from the drawbacks of making it harder to install packages and store persistent data. The main thing to consider is the networking setup - you will need to establish NAT tunnels to the VM server ports for your services.

Comment: Would the VM itself not slow anything down for the server?  If I'm running Ubuntu inside of a VM inside of say... Windows, would this not defeat the purpose or would the VM be supportive enough?  I guess this question has now changed to, how much slower is a VM than the host?

Comment: I think that'd have to be answered wit nobody's favourite answer - It depends. What are you planning to use the server for? Is it a web server? How much load is it under?

Comment: I guess at this point I should just try it all myself. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Running any OS off of a CD is significantly slower than off of a hard drive, due to the limited speed of the drive.  I would recommend running it from a USB key or other solid-state removable media instead, since they are reasonably fast and they would be able to store data persistently.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu Server does not have a live CD so you would have to use the Desktop version. It would most likely be slower, and you wouldn't be able to save configuration info. A VM is your best choice. It wouldn't be much slower than a real system, and a personal server doesn't need much power anyway. It doesn't even come with a GUI.